Fixing title of xterm even during editing a file inside it
To write a document I need to put a picture that I can capture from the screen. The picture is supposed to have an xterm which displayout uart output during rtl simulation. But I didn't capture it when I did the simulation and it takes very long time to run the simulation again and I want to finish the document now.  I have the log file that was displayed in the xterm and I thought maybe I could run xterm and read the log file there faking like it was put on there during simulation. I found I can set the title of the xterm like 'UART0_TERMINAL' by giving -title UART0_TERMINAL option but when I open the log file inside the terminal, the title of the xterm changes to like 'log/zeus_uart0.log (~/prj/chip/...)' which I don't want. I want the title bar remain as 'UART0_TERMINAL' like in simulation. Can I make the title of the xterm unchanged?

You can pass the allowTitleOps: false X11 resource string

   allowTitleOps (class AllowTitleOps)
           Specifies whether control sequences that modify the window
           title or icon name should be allowed.  The default is "true".


ex.
xterm -xrm '*allowTitleOps: false' -title 'My special title'

See also

Simply set xterm title?

Is there a way to lock terminal's title?



Wow, that works nice! Thank you!
